# Comparing Strings with compareTo requiring Object as parameter

Tags: java, string, comparable, compareto

I made a class extending ArrayList called sortedWordList that holds and sorts Strings. I would like to implement a binary search to override the indexOf method.

I cannot use compareTo to compare my Strings. I understand that I am passing the type Object to compareTo, but I believe that has to be my parameter type in order to override ArrayList's indexOf method.

My binary search algorithm may be incorrect as I have not had a chance to debug it yet so you may ignore that.

```
@Override
public int indexOf(Object o) {

    int min = 0;
    int max = len - 1;
    while (true){
        int mid = (int)((min + max)/ 2);
        if (this.get(mid).compareTo(o) == 0){
            return(mid);
        }
        if (this.get(mid).compareTo(o) < 0){
            min = mid;
        }
        else if (this.get(mid).compareTo(o) > 0){
            max = mid;
        }


        if (max == mid) break;

    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `this.get(i)` returns a `String`, you might want to make you method signature be

```
public int indexOf(String o)
```

and, instead of extending `ArrayList`, you might want to [encapsulate it](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html).

**EDIT**:

If you're forced to stick with that method signature, covert the `Object` to `String` with `String.valueOf(o)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the assignment requires me to override the method :(

Comment: Have you tried casting? `this.get(mid).compareTo((String) o)`. It is forcing you to extend ArrayList too? Looks like your assignment is forcing you to write bad code, which is unfortunate for something that is supposed to be teaching the opposite.

Comment: It's a bad idea to overload `indexOf` that way. It would confuse people who already have a hard time with methods that take `Object` instead of `E` and this would make it worse. Instead, extract the `String.valueOf` `o` (bad variable name) and feed that to `compareTo`, which does take a generic argument.

Comment: If `o` is `null` that could complicate matters. It's a good idea to check if `o` is `null` and returns "not found" if so, before doing the rest of `indexOf`.